# HTC One Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, smsmanager

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />   
<receiver android:name="com.example.set.sms" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

For some reason HTC One won't let the app listen for any incoming SMS.While debugging, it doesn't even hit the `onReceive` method. I already had a look at [HTC One, I am unable to get a SMS Broadcast Receiver to work on Android 4.1.3 on HTC one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138515/htc-one-i-am-unable-to-get-a-sms-broadcast-receiver-to-work-on-android-4-1-3-on) but didn't help.
Is this a known issue with HTC devices?

HTC One: Android 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this on my **HTC One** and this works.

**Change your receiver From:**

```
         <receiver android:name="com.example.set.sms" >
         <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
         </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
```

**To**

```
        <receiver android:name="com.mike.broadcastexample.BroadcastReceiverClass" android:exported="true" > 
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" > 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Is it really working ?I mean even after user force closed the application??

Comment: @UsmanRiaz If the application is force closed from the settings-appmanager-force close the app, this obviously any app won't work because there is no instance of the app and there is no way there will be a listener to listen to those events. But, if the app is closed(app is destyoyed), this does work.. Just make sure to register your receiver in the onResume() and unregister receiver in the onPause().

Comment: Actually i want to invoke the application via a Call. So i register the New_outgoing_call receiver in menifest.xml. plus i have no launcher activity also i.e user have to dial his pin to launch the app. I heard as of android 3.1 this feature is disabled. user have to have launch app manually for broadcast receivers to work. Do you have any other solution??Suppose if i have launcher activity and user first time launches it manually then by some reason it is forced closed in settings or phone may got rebooted then? is there any solution ?

Comment: And what is the meaning of Boot_completed broadcast receiver now? i mean when system boots ofc your app would be in stopped state it wont receives it.

Comment: Probably a late response. To response to @UsmanRiaz, yes this does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this state.

As a result, when applications are first installed, they are totally ignored by the system until and unless the user manually launches something: clicking on a launcher activity or adding an app widget, most likely.
Your app won't receive any broadcast, until the app is not started manually by the user. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols)

Comment: Well, the app runs fine on a nexus 5 which runs 4.4 without even explicitly launching it. Even after manually launching the app on HTC one, the broadcast receiver still wont work